# Exposing status information from basic c/cpp Linux application

Tags: c++, c, linux

I am trying to provide a query mechanism that is analogous to a /proc entry for a Kernel driver/module in Linux - except I have a userspace application.

This is running in Linux, c/cpp application.  I want to accomplish something like:

$ cat /proc/myapp/status

and it calls a function in my application that prints a few lines of custom status info.

Obviously I cannot use proc from a userspace application, but what would accomplish something similar from a user app?  This is embedded Linux so dbus is most likely not available

Comment: Checkout "named pipes", they may be useful here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two things you need to work out. One is what the process is going to be and the other is what is going to perform the process.

As for what the process is going to be, it can be almost anything you want. For example, you could send a signal (like `SIGUSR1`) to the process and it writes its status to a file. You could have a UNIX domain local socket that you connect to and it writes its status. You have lots of options.

The second thing is what will actually perform the process. One way would be to start your application with a special command line option, like `--status`, and it executes the steps needed to produce the status and writes them to standard output. That would allow you to do things like `MyApplication --status` to see the status or `MyApplication --status | SomeOther Application` to send the status to some other application.

You could just have a logfile open that the status gets written to when `SIGUSR1` is received. Then you can use a version of `tail -f <logfile>` followed by using `kill` to send `SIGUSR1` to your application.

It's up to you. There's no "one right way".

Comment: I do like the idea of a local socket, would be easy then to scale that to an external app asking for status over the network.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can get it with a deamon application.

You can use pthread library in your application, so that you can keep on your latest information on any files.

Although, it must have done more than using proc file system you can do what you want.

Comment: I think the asker would find it more helpful if you could be specific as to how this would be done.